# How to populate django model via list

Tags: python, django-models

I have a model named student

```
class student(models.Model):
    stdname = models.CharField
    marks = models.CharField

    def __str__(self):
        return self.stdname
```

And I have a list named

```
    student_names=['xyz', 'zyx'...]
```

Now i want to populate the model's stdname with this list. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this by using **get_or_create** method of object it will check for the name if it is not there it will create a **stdname** field and also if you want to add marks then use conditions as shown in below example.

```
for name in student_names:
    lt, created = student.objects.get_or_create(
        stdname=name,
    )
    if not created:
        lt.marks = <put your mark here>
    lt.save()
```

Comment: Sorry i have not slept in two days so pardon my brain cells but if i use 
std = student()

for name in student_names:
    std.stdname = name

std.save()

Will this work?

Comment: And what if i want to display stdname using object? Kindly help me out.